# Rebind button with wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython

I have this button :

```
 self.mybutton= wx.Button(self, -1, label= "mylabel", pos=(100,180))
 self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.Onbutton, self.mybutton)
```

and need to Bind it to another function whenspecifc radio button is choosen for exmaple :

```
def onRadiobutton(self,event) :

 if choosen radio button :

     bind the mybutton to another function
```

How can i do it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`Unbind()`](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.EvtHandler-class.html#Unbind) method to unbind your button from its handler then just bind to what ever other method you want the normal way.

```
def onButton(self, event):
    if yourRadioButton.GetValue() == True:
        self.Unbind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, handler=self.onButton, source=self.myButton)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.someOtherHandler, self.myButton)
```

Comment: You don't even have to Unbind -- Bind() will overwrite the previously bound function.

Comment: @Steven: Im no expert but it doesn't seem to overwrite the previous function. If you put `event.Skip()` in the new handler `onButton()` still gets called after... so to me it seems safer to call `Unbind()` although in most cases you would probably get way it if you left it out.